# Errro running ng serve - module has no exported member

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Something has gotten misconfigured in my app.  I've returned to a commit which I know was working before the "incident", but I get errors when running `ng serve` (listed below) and the app fails to load.  The errors refer to files in `node_modules` which I do not edit.  I have tried `npm uninstall` followed by `npm install` for the modules `@angular/common` and `@angular/forms` but this has no effect.  At this point I don't know what to do.

```
[default] Checking started in a separate process...

[default] /Users/carlson/dev/a2/manuscripta2b/node_modules/@angular/common/src/common.d.ts:19:10 
    Module '"/Users/carlson/dev/a2/manuscripta2b/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Version'.

[default] /Users/carlson/dev/a2/manuscripta2b/node_modules/@angular/common/src/version.d.ts:13:10 
    Module '"/Users/carlson/dev/a2/manuscripta2b/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Version'.

[default] /Users/carlson/dev/a2/manuscripta2b/node_modules/@angular/forms/src/version.d.ts:13:10 
    Module '"/Users/carlson/dev/a2/manuscripta2b/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Version'.
[default] /Users/carlson/dev/a2/manuscripta2b/src/app/editor/editor/editor/editor.component.ts:23:14
```

Answer (score 0):

I set up new product with `ng new foo`, then copied the src directory from the damaged app, then slowly rebuilt the dependencies in `package.json`.